# How do I invert a pygame color?

Tags: python, colors, pygame

How do I invert a pygame color?
For example how would I invert:

```
key_color = pygame.Color('grey')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) object:

> The Color class represents RGBA color values using a value range of 0 to 255 inclusive. It allows basic arithmetic operations — binary operations +, -, *, //, %, and unary operation ~ [...]

Hence you can use several operators to compute colors. The red, green and blue color channels can be accessed with the attributes `r`, `g` and `b`:

```py
key_color = pygame.Color('grey')
```

```py
inverted_color = pygame.Color(255-key_color.r, 255-key_color.g, 255-key_color.b)
```

recpectively

```py
inverted_color = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255) - key_color
```

Alternatively, the bitwise inversion (`~`) of a color can be used:

```py
inverted_color = ~key_color
```

The bitwise inverse is implemented by (`operator.__invert__(obj)`). See [Standard operators as functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

Answer (score 1):

One can invert a pygame color with:

```
key_color = pygame.Color('grey')
# one can use bit inversion (the ~ operator) on a color
inverted_color = ~key_color
# which is calculated by calling
inverted_color = key_color.__invert__()
```

per [these docs](https://valentinbasel.fedorapeople.org/doc/docu-api/pygame.Color-class.html) and [python std lib docs on `__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.invert)